# How can I delete the entity from Elastic-search if i don't know exact index name?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-template

I have indexes in elastic-search which are named as follows-

1. indexName-2017-01-25
2. indexName-2017-01-24
3. indexName-2017-01-23
4. ...and so on

All above indexes has same 'type', lets say "indexType".

Now I want to delete a record with a given "id" which might be present in any of the above indexes and user of my API will provide me following-

1. id of the entity to be deleted.
2. Index prefix i.e. "indexName-*".
3. type of index i.e. "indexType".

How can I write a query in JAVA to delete an entity with given above information?

Comment: Hope this article help you. https://damienbod.com/2015/02/10/searching-multiple-indices-and-types-in-elasticsearch/

Comment: It has lot of links embedded and the doc says it for searching. I need it for deletion as searching I have already implemented. @AshutoshTripathi

Comment: search dont return the document along with index and type ?